# How to manually select the android sdk build-tools version in azure pipeline?

Tags: android, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, android-signing

I am trying to sign my `apk` file with `apksigner` and `zipalign` in `azure.pipeline`. I want to manually specify the build-tools version.

Currently it is using default version `24.0.3` for `apksigner` and `19.1.0` for `zipalign`.

How can I select the specific build-tools version in the [android signing task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/android-signing?view=azure-devops)?

Here's the log.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apksignerFile` and `zipalignFile` parameters ans specify to the file with the version you want.

> The location of the apksigner/zipalign executable used during signing.
>   Defaults to the zipalign found in the Android SDK version folder your
>   application builds against.

In YAML:

```
#apksignerFile: # Optional
#zipalignFile: # Optional
```

For example:

```
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk' 
    apksign: true 
    apksignerFile: C:/path/to/version/24.0
    zipalign: true 
    zipalignFile: C:/path/to/version/25.0
```

In the designer:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide me with an eg of how can I specify the version of `apksignerFile` and `zipalignFile` in the `yaml` file.

Comment: this is not working. I tried this `apksignerFile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\apksigner` and this `zipalignFile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign`

Comment: I have uploaded some screenshots. The file location is different.

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Comment: Hosted agent `Hosted VS2017`

Comment: So I think this is the reason, to hosted agent don't has the versions you want, he has only a specific version, try to download an agent and use it.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) it says that all the latest build tools are installed.

Comment: So I checked the build and found that hosted agent is `Hosted macOS (Hosted macOS)` not `Hosted VS2017`

Comment: In the Hosted agent you can't know which versions installed and where. I suggest install an agent on your PC/Build server.

Comment: I am getting `Error: Cannot find any file based on d:\a\1\s\**\Release\*.apk.` The project is building, and the apk file is in the drop.